# not able to install parcel on my windows 10 laptop

Tags: node.js, parceljs

I tried to install parcel on my windows 10 laptop, but this happened:

```
$ npm install -D parcel@next
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
```

Comment: these are warnings about it's dependencies. it has been installed.

Comment: Please explain the question in more detail